# Limit of $\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$ where z is complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the limit of $\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$ as n goes to infinity where z is complex number and $|z|>1$. I'm getting confused because this would give infinity over negative infinity and in the real numbers I would us L'Hopital's rule n times in order to solve but I'm not sure that I can do that for the complex number z. Please help.

Comment: First rewrite as $$\frac{1}{1-z^n}-1$$ to help yourself some.

Comment: so then the limit is -1?

Comment: Whoops sorry had a typo. Brain is mushy after a long day.

Comment: It's okay I think I see what you mean. So the limit would just give you -1.

Comment: There you go! Good work.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Here's a fun exercise: what if $|z| < 1$? What if $|z|=1$? (Something funny happens if $|z| = 1$..)

Comment: I have those cases figured out already :) It was interesting